# php header Location immediately?

Tags: php, redirect, header

Why the Location header does not redirect the page immediately?
It always performs the entire process before redirecting?

I will give some example:

```
header('Location:http://www.php.net');
$f = fopen('demo.txt','w+');
fwrite($f,'Test');
fclose($f);
```

It always generates the TXT file before redirecting to `http://www.php.net`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, `header()` just sends certain header to browser. PHP still continues running the script after that. If you don't want to stop running the script, just use `die;` or `exit;` - it will stop processing the script further.

Comment: not a matter of not liking, quite the contrary
just do not know how it worked, felt that the process died immediately when the header was sent

I thought the header was sent first of all making the processing caught page

I really need the process to continue affixes the header location in order to finalize the system and generate logs

Comment: @Lelis that's another question

Comment: Thank you for this.  I can't believe I overlooked such an obvious solution.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the `header()` function does not redirect, it sends a header. A browser may (theoretically) completely ignore it and choose to continue parsing the page. If you wish the script to not process after sending the header, fire `die()` or `exit()` immediately after.

Answer (score 1):

> Why the Location header does not redirect the page immediately?

Just because it doesn't redirect anything at all. It's browser who will brake current connection (causing script to stop) to requests another page. And there is a network latency.

> It always performs the entire process before redirecting?

Not always. It's just not guaranteed.

> I really need the process to continue affixes the header location in order to finalize the system and generate logs

with mod_php you will need `ignore_user_abort()` and with php-fpm it's `fastcgi_finish_request‎()` to guarantee entire script execution.

Comment: then when I set Location header, it "speaks" to the browser that it should go to another page

He always runs the whole process before redirecting?
Not always. Not only is guaranteed.

you could tell me what factors influence this process?

Comment: @Lelis network latency only unless you took some precautions.

Comment: @ Col. Shrapnel, but this could influence the whole process, not only in the case of the browser to redirect or not. correct?

Comment: what process you're talking about?

Comment: I refer to the script. network latency could prevent or correct the redirect so stop running script?

Comment: @Lelis I still don't understand your question. There is a time required for the response and another request to travel from the server and back. There is a time required for the script to finish it's job. If T1 < T2, script fails.

Comment: My question has already been resolved, you guys helped me a lot, @Col. Shrapnel, I will follow your tip about the ignore_user_abort (). Thank you very much

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2931/discussion-between-lelis-and-col-shrapnel)